# Computing $\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx$$
How to calculate this integral? I tried using integration by part without too much success. The indefinite integral of it seemed to be to complicated,  but the answer should probably be something like $\frac{{\pi}\ln 3}2$ . I only know that $$\int\frac1{\sin x}dx=\ln\left|\frac1{\sin x}-\frac1{\tan x }\right|+C$$, and was told that it has something to do with the integral.  I hope someone can answer this question.  Thanks.

EDIT: sorry, but I mistakenly got the lower limit wrong. It should be $\frac{\pi}3$

Solution: (inspired by @Claude Leibovici)

Sub $$x=\frac{\pi}2+y$$
Then $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx$$
$$=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} {\frac{{\frac{\pi}2}+y}{\cos y}} dy$$
$$=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} {\frac{{\frac{\pi}2}}{\cos y}} dy + \int_{\frac{-\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} {\frac y{\cos y}}dy$$
$$=\frac{{\pi}\ln3}2+0$$
$$=\frac{{\pi}\ln3}2$$
Again, thanks for those who put efforts to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{\pi/2}^{2 \pi/3} \frac{x}{\sin{x}}dx$? It's a bit tricky integral ...http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%2Fsin%28x%29

Comment: Yup,  but it should be some kind of special case that do not need to completely break it up

Comment: Well, this is what Wolfram|Alpha returned:
$$\small \int_{\frac{π}{2}}^{\frac{2 π}{3}} \frac{x}{\sin{x}} dx = \frac{1}{12} i (24 i C + 6 (\operatorname*{Li_2}(-(-1)^{1/3}) - 4 \operatorname*{Li_2}((-1)^{2/3})) + 3 π^2 + 16 i π \tanh^{-1}((-1)^{2/3}))≈1.0101$$
Where $C$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) and $\operatorname*{Li_2}$ is the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) function.

Comment: The integral diverges at $x=\pi$. The [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) might exist. There is [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348597) for the indefinite integral. We might also employ the ideas from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2997917).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Israel gave the answer : no solution except using  polylogarithm functions and, more than likely, numerical method would be required.

What you could do is first set $x=\frac \pi 2+y$ which would give $$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx=\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\frac{\frac \pi 2+y}{\cos(y)}\,dy=\frac \pi 2\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\frac{dy}{\cos(y)}+\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\frac{y}{\cos(y)}\,dy$$ The first integral is simple (using the tangent half-angle subsitution).

For the second one, we could expand the integrand as a Taylor series around $y=0$. This would give
$$\frac{y}{\cos(y)}=y+\frac{y^3}{2}+\frac{5 y^5}{24}+\frac{61 y^7}{720}+O\left(y^9\right)$$ $$\int\frac{y}{\cos(y)}\,dy=\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{8}+\frac{5 y^6}{144}+\frac{61
   y^8}{5760}+O\left(y^{10}\right)$$ $$\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\frac{y}{\cos(y)}\,dy=\frac{\pi ^2}{72}+\frac{\pi ^4}{10368}+\frac{5 \pi ^6}{6718464}+\frac{61 \pi
   ^8}{9674588160}+\cdots$$ Finally, we end with $$I=\frac \pi 2 \frac{\log (3)}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{72}+\frac{\pi ^4}{10368}+\frac{5 \pi ^6}{6718464}+\frac{61 \pi
   ^8}{9674588160}+\cdots\approx 1.010096$$ while numerical integration would lead to $\approx 1.010102$.

**Edit**

For the second integral, instead of a Taylor expansion, we could use a Padé approximant such as $$\frac{y}{\cos(y)}\approx\frac{y+\frac{7 }{75}y^3+\frac{1}{200} y^5} { 1-\frac{61 }{150}y^2}$$ which would make $$\int_0^{\frac \pi 6} \frac{y}{\cos(y)}\,dy\approx \frac{703125 \log \left(\frac{5400}{5400-61 \pi ^2}\right)}{453962}-\frac{\pi ^2
   \left(92784+61 \pi ^2\right)}{25719552}$$ and then $$I\approx 1.0101022740$$ while numerical integration would lead to $\approx 1.0101022541$.

Comment: Ah, yes, but considering it as a definite integral,  maybe we don't need to calculate the indefinite integral completely?

Comment: sorry, but I mistakenly got the lower limit wrong. It should be $\frac{\pi}3$

Comment: Er, nothing. I have found out the solution. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative $\int \frac{x}{\sin(x)}\; dx$ is not an elementary function.
It can be expressed in terms of the dilog function.  I do not expect your definite integral to have an elementary expression either.

Comment: Hmmm, but I think there might be another way to calculate this definite integral without directly calculating it

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (inspired by @Claude Leibovici)

Sub $$x=\frac{\pi}2+y$$
Then $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx$$
$$=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} {\frac{{\frac{\pi}2}+y}{\cos y}} dy$$
$$=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} {\frac{{\frac{\pi}2}}{\cos y}} dy + \int_{\frac{-\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} {\frac y{\cos y}}dy$$
$$=\frac{{\pi}\ln3}2+0$$
$$=\frac{{\pi}\ln3}2$$

Comment: Well done ! $\to +1$.