# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I have been trying to do the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} dx$$

**My Attempt**

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)} dx= \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\csc(x) dx= \Bigg[2x  \csc(x)dx\Bigg]_0^{\pi/2} -\int_0^{\pi/2}  2x\int\csc(x)dx dx$$

$$\Bigg[2x  \csc(x)\Bigg]_0^{\pi/2} -\int_0^{\pi/2}  2x\ln(\csc(x)-\cot(x)) dx
$$
How do you proceed from here? How do you solve this integral? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think the integral does not converge as you wrote it.

Comment: What about the points with $\sin x=0$?

Comment: This is clearly divergent. If you are interested in a continuation or some function that can be expressed in some region as an integral you might say so, but as-is there is no meaningful interpretation.

Comment: The integral does not converge.

Comment: I corrected the bounds

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714146/348034) answer the question?

Comment: I thought you were looking simply for a convergence test!

Comment: How do you explain the steps you did in integration by parts?